# Generic way in MySQL to get the top results

Tags: sql, mysql

Say for instance I have a table which has names of people and their ages. I want a generic query in MySQL which will pull out the n oldest people.

I could use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Say Frank and Emily are both 99 years old. The `limit 1` will only return one of their names. In psuedo-sql I would want the query to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE MAX(age);
```

I know you can also do this with a subquery, but there must be an easier, more generic way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, subquery is it. For example, everyone with the top 3 ages:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE age IN (SELECT DISTINCT age FROM people ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 3)
```

or just the top age:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE age = (SELECT MAX(age) FROM people)
```

Comment: Cletus, why would you use a LIMIT in the subquery rather than the MAX aggregate? And if you're doing a limit 1, why the DISTINCT?

Comment: Coolio. Bah, the subquery seems a little awkward.

Answer (score 1):

> I know you can also do this with a subquery, but there must be an easier, more generic way of achieving this?

Not in ANSI SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE age = 
  (select MAX(age) from people);
```

Comment: I disagree: this is ANSI/ISO SQL without a subquery: SELECT P1.ID, P2.Age
  FROM people AS P1
       INNER JOIN people AS P2
          ON P1.ID = P2.ID
 GROUP 
    BY P1.ID, P2.Age
HAVING P1.Age = MAX(P2age);

Comment: Oops, ignore comment (I can't delete it).

Answer (score 0):

@cletus -

```
SELECT * 
FROM people 
WHERE age IN (SELECT DISTINCT age 
              FROM people 
              ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 3)
```

LIMIT does not work in a sub query in MySQL.